# Как сделать переадресацию при помощи ajax и php?

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax запросом вызывается php скрипт. В нем завершается текущая сессия и в конце требуется обновить страницу. Делал 2 способами:

- 1-й способ: `header ("refresh: 0");`
- 2-й способ: `header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

В обоих случаях выдает одинаковую ошибку в responseText. Как заставить это работать?

Comment: Мб передавать переменную и из onload обновлять страницу?

Comment: Какая ошибка?

Comment: ладно это понятно. мне больше интересно почему из php не получается? Или так вообще нельзя потому что php вызывается с помощью ajax?

Comment: ошибка:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\koxan.ru\www\PHP\authOut.php:11) in Z:\home\koxan.ru\www\PHP\authOut.php on line 15

Comment: дело в том что перезагрузка страници обязательна! А как известно javascript обмануть проще всего (какому нить умнику)

Answer (score 3):

Если делаете аяксом, то прямо в скрипте после того, как он выполнится, сделайте

```
window.location.href="/url/to/update/php"
```

Это надо сделать в JavaScript.

Comment: Можешь в ответе от ajax передавать путь, куда тебе надо перейти а в JavaScript уже подставишь и перейдешь

Answer (score 2):

В callback-функции укажите location.reload(). После получения ответа страница перезагрузится.

Answer (score -1):

Можно одной строкой

```
header('Refresh: 0; URL='.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

и самое главное строка должна быть выше закрывающего тега </head>

Comment: В этой ситуации не можно. Юзер ждет ответа аякса, а перезагрузить нужно страницу.